# Wobble in volumetric fixed step raymarching

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, webgl

I'm running into a bug with my shaders. For the vertex:

```
varying vec3 worldPosition;
varying vec3 viewDirection;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    worldPosition = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0));
    viewDirection = normalize(worldPosition - cameraPosition);

}
```

For the fragment:

```
uniform float time;
varying vec3 worldPosition;
varying vec3 viewDirection;

/// utilities

bool sphereHit (vec3 p)
{
    return distance(p,vec3(0,0,0)) < 1.0;
}

#define STEP_SIZE 0.01

bool raymarchHit (vec3 in_position, vec3 direction)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
    if ( sphereHit(in_position) )
        return true;

        in_position += direction * STEP_SIZE;
    }
    return false;
}

void main() {
    if(raymarchHit(worldPosition, viewDirection)){
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); 
    }else{
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.5); 
    }


}
```

I'm trying to set up a raymarching shader so I attached this to a rotating cube in ThreeJS but instead of a fixed, camera facing, sphere/circle which was the goal I seem to get a sphere that seems to wobble from the cube's rotation (but in truth volume containing mesh itself shouldn't really matter correct?). I haven't been able to pin down the cause.

Comment: Added a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/860qmctL/13/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused, because (from [OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00 Specification  - 4.3.5 Varying](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf#page=37&zoom=100,153,314))

> varying variables are set per vertex and are interpolated in a perspective-correct manner
>   over the primitive being rendered.

To make your algorithm work, you have to interpolate the direction of the ray `noperspective`.
Since GLSL ES 1.00 does not provide [Interpolation qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers) you have to find a workaround.

Compute the ray in the fragment shader:

```c
void main() {
    bool hit = raymarchHit(worldPosition, normalize(worldPosition - cameraPosition));
    gl_FragColor = hit ? vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0) : vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.5); 
}
```

See the example:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material, stats;

class VolumetricNebula_sp {
    constructor(vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
        this.clock = new THREE.Clock();
        this.uniforms = {
            time: {
                type: 'float',
                value: 2.0
            }
        }
        this.geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(4.0, 4.0, 4.0); // width, height, depth

        this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            uniforms: this.uniforms,
            fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
            vertexShader: vertexShader,
            transparent: true
        })

        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
        scene.add(this.mesh);
    }
    update() {
        this.uniforms.time.value = this.clock.getElapsedTime();
        this.mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        this.mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
        this.mesh.rotation.z += 0.01;
    }
}

function init() {
    // Renderer.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add renderer to page
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create camera.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 5;

    // Create scene.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    volVertexShader = `varying highp vec3 worldPosition;
    //varying vec3 viewDirection;

    void main() {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

        worldPosition = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0));
        //viewDirection = normalize(worldPosition - cameraPosition);

    }`;
    volFragShader = `uniform float time;
    varying vec3 worldPosition;
    //varying vec3 viewDirection;

    /// utilities

    bool sphereHit (vec3 p)
    {
        return distance(p,vec3(0,0,0)) < 1.0;
    }

    #define STEP_SIZE 0.1

    bool raymarchHit (vec3 in_position, vec3 direction)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if ( sphereHit(in_position) )
                return true;
            in_position += direction * STEP_SIZE;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void main() {
        bool hit = raymarchHit(worldPosition, normalize(worldPosition - cameraPosition));
        gl_FragColor = hit ? vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0) : vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.5); 
    }`;

    var volumetricNebulaCenterPiece = new VolumetricNebula_sp(volVertexShader, volFragShader);

    // Add listener for window resize.
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

    // Add stats to page.
    //stats = new Stats();
    //document.body.appendChild( stats.dom );
    
    function animate() {
      volumetricNebulaCenterPiece.update();
       renderer.render(scene, camera);
      //stats.update();
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
    animate();
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
init();
```

```css
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
canvas { display: block; }
```

```html
<!--script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ahh I see, I had found a temporary workaround by increasing the container volume's number of vertexes but this fixes it properly! Thanks!